# ALIZE platform installation and execution the examples

Tags: voice-recognition

I recently program using the speaker recognition lib - ALIZE. But I got some questions about how to install and execute the demo. Could somebody help me to see what's wrong with my order of installation and execution.

I use Mac OS system:

1, Download lib ALIZE and LIA-RAL, using the *aclocal, automake, autoconf, ./configure and make* for each lib.

2, I downloaded the demo, I found the demo from Internet:
http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/doc_en.html

3, I copied the LIA_RAL/bin into the XX/bin/. XX is the demo I found.

4, I compiler with bash + XX.sh in the demo.

Two errors I found when I do the step 4. One is I could not found the bin/sfbcep, could somebody explain me what is this. The one error is *bus error 10*, which I have also no idea about.

Comment: Can you post the full error log?

Comment: The link and general subdomain at http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/doc_en.html doesn't seem to work anymore. Did Alize/LIA_RAL drop off the face of the Earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sfbcep` is part of [SPro](https://gforge.inria.fr/projects/spro).
You may want to compile it yourself, rather than rely on the binary they provide.

edit: link updated to Spro5

Comment: @cindywmiao I'm having precisely the same `Bus error 10` issue, even after doing everything you did in your initial question, downloading Spro 4.0.1, installing via `./configure; make; make install`, and copying the `sfbcep` binary from `/usr/local/bin` to `XX/scripts/sfbcep`. What exactly was your fix?

Comment: @acannon828 : once you've installed spro, you don't need to copy the binaries any longer. Spro binaries are in the PATH now, you just have to modify your scripts accordingly (do not use the full path to `sfbcep`, and replace it with `sfbcep` only).

Comment: I am also facing the same bus 10 error on mac 10.11.6 (el capitan) when running any alize binary, as for sfbcep I have compiled it and it seem to work fine

Comment: @cindywmiao : How you are able to run Alize demo app on Mac os?Please guide me , i also trying the same.